# Grails grailApplication.controllerClasses sort controller by package

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, grails-orm, gsp

I have the following code that grabs all controllers, sorts it, and outputs in li tags:

```
<g:each var="c" in="${grailsApplication.controllerClasses.sort { it.fullName } }">
        <li<%= c.logicalPropertyName == controllerName ? ' class="active"' : '' %>>
                <g:link controller="${c.logicalPropertyName}">${c.naturalName}</g:link>
        </li>
</g:each>
```

I have a need to filter out controllers by package i.e. grab controller from a certain package.

For example:

```
com.app.module.mars.controller.HelloController
com.app.module.venus.controller.PrintController
```

As you can see I'm packaging controllers by modules, so mars will have its own set of controllers and venus will have its own. Then in the UI I want to use the above code (with some filter) which will show modules as main-menus and their controllers as dropdowns.

How can I apply such a filter? Or if you could guide me in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GrailsClassUtils.isClassBelowPackage()`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsClassUtils.html#isClassBelowPackage%28java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%29) which takes a class and a list of packages as the arguments. So this should do the trick:

```
GrailsClassUtils.isClassBelowPackage(c.class, ['com.app.module.mars'])
```

Edit: `grailsApplication.controllerClasses` probably gives you a list of `GrailsClass` objects, so you'd want to use `c.clazz` instead of `c.class` like

```
grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { c ->
    GrailsClassUtils.isClassBelowPackage(c.clazz, ['com.app.module.mars'])
}
```

Comment: I am at a beginner level. So I am not quite understanding how would I implement that. Which one do I need to use GrailsClassUtils.isClass... or grailsApplication.Controllerclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Collection#groupBy`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) to group the controller classes by package name.

I don't have a Grails system to make a quick test right now, but this would be a little example of grouping classes by package name:

```
def classes = [Integer, List, String]
def classesByPackage = classes.groupBy { it.package.name }
assert classesByPackage == ['java.lang': [Integer, String], 'java.util': [List]]
```

You can then iterate through each packageName to make each menu and through each class under that package name to make each menu item. Something like...

```
classesByPackage.each { packageName, packageClasses ->
    println "Menu $packageName"
    packageClasses.each { println "  Item $it.simpleName" }
}
```

... but with GSP-style loops :)